# "Translated in" vs. "translated to"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, prepositions

Both of these seem very similar to me. Is there any difference between "books translated **to** English" and "books translated **in** English"?

Google search returns many results for both (> 400,000), though "translated *to* English" gives more results than "translated *in* English". If only one of them is correct, then why the confusion?

Comment: From one language *to* another ... from Spanish *to* (or *into*) English.

Comment: Not sure where you get the Google figures from. I get 20k for "books translated in English", 56k for "books translated to English", and 127k for "books translated into English". You might also be interested in supporting our proposed sister site specifically for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). Thank you.

Comment: @RegDwighт Forgot to mention that I had googled only for "translated in English" and "translated to English". Thanks for pointing to ELL site.

Comment: This is a "popular question" with zero upvotes! Amusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither - it's *books translated **into** English*. Some relevant usage figures from Google Books...

> ["books translated into English"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22books%20translated%20to%20English%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22books%20translated%20into%20English%22&oq=%22books%20translated%20into%20English%22&gs_l=serp.3...3153.3366.0.3710.2.2.0.0.0.0.62.112.2.2.0...0.0...1c.1.SU74GAufgOw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=165ee1c427b7541a&bpcl=37189454&biw=1311&bih=870) 83,200 hits
>
> ["books translated to English"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22books%20translated%20to%20English%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) 85 hits
>
> ["books translated in English"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22books%20translated%20to%20English%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22books%20translated%20in%20English%22&oq=%22books%20translated%20in%20English%22&gs_l=serp.3...116744.117368.1.117622.4.2.2.0.0.1.198.244.1j1.2.0...0.0...1c.1.gZZRMJ0U5cQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=165ee1c427b7541a&bpcl=37189454&biw=1311&bih=870) 198 hits

There's no principle of grammar, logic, or semantics involved here. It's just that nearly everyone falls into line and repeats what they hear nearly everyone else say - unlike *this* sentence, where people are actually about evenly split over whether they ["fall **into** line"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22if%20you%20had%20have%20done%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22we%20fall%20into%20line%22&oq=%22we%20fall%20into%20line%22&gs_l=serp.3...75660.79185.4.79583.11.11.0.0.0.1.110.674.10j1.11.0...0.0...1c.1.fevzZ3MYXOI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=165ee1c427b7541a&bpcl=37189454&biw=1311&bih=870) or ["fall **in** line"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22if%20you%20had%20have%20done%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22we%20fall%20in%20line%22&oq=%22we%20fall%20in%20line%22&gs_l=serp.3...4799.4976.5.5310.2.2.0.0.0.0.53.99.2.2.0...0.0...1c.1.psG69hLJ0Qw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=165ee1c427b7541a&bpcl=37189454&biw=1311&bih=870) (but they never ["fall **to** line"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22was%20translated%20to%20english%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22we%20fall%20to%20line%22&oq=%22we%20fall%20to%20line%22&gs_l=serp.3...26552.26968.8.27318.3.3.0.0.0.1.125.305.1j2.3.0...0.0...1c.1.a2YHl7E7lMw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=165ee1c427b7541a&bpcl=37189454&biw=1311&bih=870) in that sense).

Comment: Is it like, because there was confusion between `in` and `to`, people started using BOTH?

Comment: @user13107: Don't forget both put together are barely 1/300th of the "standard" form, so they don't mean much anyway. Others may differ, but in my idiolect, **to** is non-standard but just about "okay", whereas **in** is effectively unknown/illiterate. So if those few Google Books results mean anything at all, they're probably telling me that non-native speakers disproportionately choose *"in"* instead of *"into"*. There are even 19 hits for ["**in to**"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22books+translated+in+to+English%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), which is 100% illiterate.

Comment: Google ignores stop words like "in" and "to" (but not "into"), so your usage figures may not be correct.

Comment: @dbkk: It's a bit more complicated than just "Google ignores 'stop' words" - and in any case, Google **Books** uses a different "guesstimate" algorithm to the standard "Google Internet". Your point is "sorta" valid, but my point isn't significantly affected by the possibility that the "headline" figures are skewed by an order of magnitude (in either direction).

Answer (score 2):

In the given context, it's always *translated into* not *translated to* or *translated in to*. You could very well say that "cats" translate to "tomcats", which is a totally different thing.